# unexpected behavior of replace

Tags: r

I need help with the `replace()` command

```
replace(c(3,2,2,1),1:3,4:6)
```

I was expecting an output of `6,5,5,4` but got `4,5,6,1`

What am i doing wrong?

My understanding of what replace is this: it looks up index values of elements of the first argument in the second argument (e.g. 3 is the 3rd element in 1:3)  and then replaces it with elements in the third argument with the same index (e.g. 3rd element in 4:6 is 6 thus the reason for me expecting the first element in the vector to be 6)

Thank you. (replace help file doesn't have example... need to ask for clarification here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is all given in the description of `replace()`, just read carefully:

```
 ‘replace’ replaces the values in ‘x’ with indices given in ‘list’
 by those given in ‘values’. If necessary, the values in ‘values’
 are recycled.


x <- c(3, 2, 2, 1)
i <- 1:3
new <- 4:6
```

so this means in your case:

```
x[i] <- new
```

Comment: "x[i] <- new" that's exactly how replace() is defined. thanks for that... next time i will type the function name first in the console to give more clarity.

Answer (score 6):

While `replace` doesn't give the behaviour your desired, to achieve what you were intending is quite easy to do using `match`:

```
new[match(x,i)]
```

Answer (score 2):

That command says to take the vector c(3, 2, 2, 1) and to replace the components with indices in 1:3 by the values given by the vector 4:6. This gives c(4, 5, 6, 1).